# Is there a way to make a label, spawn specific distance away from another label in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, bots, chatbot

I'm creating a chatbot, and I'm just getting into the frontend. I'm using a read-only text input as the text that that appears on the screen after you input and click send, I'm not able to find a way to create a label, below the label that was already done, currently the text just overlaps the text which I typed before and clicked send, I went it to be created below, Please Help

Python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import re
import time

class MyFL(FloatLayout):
    global input
    input = ObjectProperty(None)
    global button
    button = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        a = 0.95
        while len(self.input.text) > 0:
            self.add_widget(MyTextInput(text='> ' + self.input.text, pos_hint={'y':a}))
            a = a - 0.05
            self.input.text = ""


class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFL()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Kv file

```
<FloatLayout>:

    input:input
    button:button

    TextInput:
        id: input
        multiline: False
        hint_text: "Say Something"
        size_hint: 1, 0.05
        font_size: 20

    Button:
        id:button
        size_hint: 0.05, 0.05
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.06 }
        on_press: root.btn()

<MyTextInput>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    readonly: True
    multiline:True
```

Comment: Try using a `BoxLayout` to contain the chat.